# Haskell module restricted sharing

Tags: haskell, module

I have 2 modules which share code, so I want to factor out a third module for this code sharing. But I only want those first 2 modules to be able to see it (via `import`) because the code is not re-usable to the outside world. Thus any other module would be blocked from importing the third module. Is this doable?

Alternatively the third module does have some code that is useful to the outside world, and some that is not (but rather only to the first 2 modules). Is there a way to qualify its export list?

Comment: In the cabal file, `exposed-modules` for the importable modules and `other-modules` for the non-importable modules.

Comment: I'm using `stack` which automatically generates the `cabal` file from `package.yaml`. So is there a way to put this info in `package.yaml`?

Comment: Comment at the top of the `cabal` file:
_-- This file has been generated from package.yaml by hpack version 0.31.2._

Comment: Sorry I never used `package.yaml`, I don't know.

Comment: @LoHaBuyshan2 If you've solved your problem, then you should post an answer to your own question, to help any future comers.

Comment: Thanks Stephane for your solution. FYI, `stack` integration is explained in https://mmhaskell.com/blog/2017/7/17/cleaning-up-our-projects-with-hpack